# MySQL delete and remove from many-to-many table in one transaction

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, many-to-many, model-associations

Is it possible to delete from association table (many-to-many) and insert same row to it in the same transaction?

This is my association table:

```
CREATE TABLE image_tag (
  imageid bigint(19) NOT NULL, 
  tagid   bigint(19) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (imageid, tagid));
ALTER TABLE image_tag ADD INDEX FKimage_tag587679 (tagid), ADD CONSTRAINT  FKimage_tag587679 FOREIGN KEY (tagid) REFERENCES tag (id);
ALTER TABLE image_tag ADD INDEX FKimage_tag426448 (imageid), ADD CONSTRAINT FKimage_tag426448 FOREIGN KEY (imageid) REFERENCES image (id);
```

When I am creating a new image and inserting into image, insert into tag and insert into image_tag in one transaction, everything works.

The problem occurs when I want to to update Image and I:

- start transaction
- update image with given $id
- call: DELETE FROM image_tag WHERE imageid = $id
- check whether image_tag is empty for imageid = $id (and it is)
- retrieve IDs of new tags (some of them remains same)
- try to insert into image_tag ...but I receive an exception

Exception:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydatabase`.`image_tag`, CONSTRAINT `FKimage_tag426448` FOREIGN KEY  (`imageid`) REFERENCES `image` (`id`))
```

Data:

```
Original data: (194, 123), (194, 225), (194, 291)
New data: (194, 123), (194, 225), (194, 65)
```

Source code (in PHP):

```
if ($editation) {
  if ($values->image->isOk()) {
    $url = $img->load($values->id)->getUrl();
    $values->image->move($this->wwwDir . "/" . $url);
  } else {
    $url = null;
  }      
  $img->update($values->name, $values->descr, $url, null, $featured);
} else {
  $uname = $img->createUniqueName($values->name);
  $url = ImageManager::PATH . "/" . $uname . ".svg";
  $values->image->move($this->wwwDir . "/" . $url);
  $img->create($userId, $values->name, $url, $values->descr, null, $featured);      
}

// Delete old image-tag associations if any
$this->db->query('DELETE FROM image_tag WHERE imageid = %i', $img->getId());

// Save tags and assign them to image
$tagIds = $this->tagManager->saveTags($values->tags);
$assoc = (new Dao\ImageTag())->setDb($this->db);
//throw new \Exception(implode(",", $tagIds));
foreach ($tagIds as $tagId) {     
  // EXCEPTION IS THROWED HERE (but only after editation)
  $assoc->create($img->getId(), $tagId);      
}
```

Comment: Can you show some more sample data and explain more why you need to delete? From your original to new data, it looks like the only row that is changing is the last one, and I'm not sure why you can't just run an `update` query?

Comment: Because I don't want to provide additional logic - which tag i should keep and which not - I just simply delete all and then add all current tags, no matter which were same and which not. Do you consider this approach as bad?

Comment: Well it's certainly dangerous, unless you wrap it all in a transaction. What happens if the delete works but the insertion fails? You could lose a lot of data. Also, I'm not sure you can run a delete and an insert in the same query. Are you dead set against updating? I think it might be a better approach, if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you try to update your image_tag with invalid id? ..null, 0, -1 or something else?

Look to your code. I suppose $img and $values->image are not the same, but you load $img only when $values->image is provided. However, you try to update image_tag every time.